# TinkerPop finds edges with common out nodes

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

for vertex A, how to find edges from A that shares same out vertex? 
I can use count() to find the vertices that each has multiple out vertices, but I only want to find the edges that from A and ending at the same vertices.

Answer (score 0):

This query would give you want you need:

```
g.V('A').outE().group().by(inV()).by().unfold()
    .filter(select(values).count(local).is(gt(1)))
```